Unable to Pass Variable between two stages targeting two Virtual Machines within YAML Pipeline
Over the last couple of days, I have been trying to get a variable to be passed from Stage 1 which runs on Server 1 via ADO Environment, to output on Stage 2 which is executed on another VM (Server2).
Is this possible to do via ADO YAML Pipeline?
UPDATED
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: DevRepo
      type: git
      name: ProjectDevDevRepo
      ref: refs/heads/Dev-Pipeline01

stages:
  - stage: stage1    
    jobs:
      - deployment: dev
        displayName: Running Deployment    
        environment: 
          name: 'Develop SQL'
          resourceType: virtualMachine
          tags: 'Server1'

         strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - powershell: |
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]this is a stage output variable"                  
                name: MyOutputVar
 
      - stage: stage2
          dependsOn: stage1
          variables:
            myStageAVar: $[ stageDependencies.stage1.dev.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal'] ]        
            jobs:
            - deployment: qa
              displayName: Running Deployment    
              environment: 
                name: 'Develop SQL'
                resourceType: virtualMachine
                tags: 'Server2'

              strategy:
                runOnce:
                  deploy:
                    steps:
                      - powershell: |
                          Write-Host "Variable content: $(myStageAVar)"


To see if it is possible to pass variable between 1 VM using Environments to another VM using Environments within ADO.

You're setting the output variable myStageVal twice - try removing the second task:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal; isOutput=true]this is a stage output variable"                  
    name: MyOutputVar
  - powershell: |
      Get-ChildItem Env:
      Write-Host "Set variable myStageVal to 'this is a stage output variable'"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal; isOutput=true]this is a stage output variable"  

Also, double-check you're using the right syntax to reference the output variable in the other stage, as per Levels of output variables

Thanks for the advice Rui, I have removed the second myStageVal and re-ran the pipeline and am still unable to see the variable printed in Stage2.

Check the link I've posted - you might be using the wrong syntax when trying to reference the output variable.

I made the changes (See update in original Post) and just got the output Variable content:  not printing out the variable.

@JabbaIT take a good look at Wade's answer.

Please fix as below:

remove space before isOutput=true when you set the variable in 1st stage, otherwise the output will not work.

Use format as below in 2nd stage:


variables:
      myStageAVar: $[ stageDependencies.stage1.dev.outputs['dev.MyOutputVar.myStageVal'] ] 

The full sample(i commented some code):
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

# resources:
#   repositories:
#     - repository: DevRepo
#       type: git
#       name: ProjectDevDevRepo
#       ref: refs/heads/Dev-Pipeline01

stages:
  - stage: stage1    
    jobs:
      - deployment: dev
        displayName: Running Deployment    
        environment: 
          name: 'Develop SQL'
        #   resourceType: virtualMachine
        #   tags: 'Server1'

        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - powershell: |
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]this is a stage output variable"  
                name: MyOutputVar
              - script: echo $(myStageVal)
              - script: echo $(MyOutputVar.myStageVal)
              # - powershell: |
              #     Get-ChildItem Env:
              #     Write-Host "Set variable myStageVal to 'this is a stage output variable'"
              #     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal; isOutput=true]this is a stage output variable"   


  - stage: stage2
    dependsOn: stage1
    variables:
      myStageAVar: $[ stageDependencies.stage1.dev.outputs['dev.MyOutputVar.myStageVal'] ]  
    jobs:
      - deployment: qa
        displayName: Running Deployment    
        environment: 
          name: 'Develop SQL2'
        #   resourceType: virtualMachine
        #   tags: 'Server2'

        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - powershell: |
                    Write-Host "Output variable from stage1: $(myStageAVar)"
                #     Write-Host "Variable content: $(myStageAVar)"
                # - powershell: |
                #     Get-ChildItem Env:
                #     Write-Host "Retrieved variable myStageAVar as $(myStageAVar)"

The result:


Hi Wade, are you sure that variable myStageAVar is set correctly? You're referencing job name dev twice.

Yes, you can check my output screenshot.

Oh yes, didn't pay attention to the screenshot - sorry about that. I was asking because I haven't found that particular syntax in the documentation. Thanks for the quick feedback.

You can find similar syntax for the usage in doc when environment and runonce used, although it's job reuse.

Finally, I got the answer to the problem. You have to use reourceName to be able to access the Variables. I was using Tags which would not allow the pipeline to access the variables
Code example below
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - deployment: VMDeployWin11
    displayName: Deploy to Win11
    environment: 
      name: env-Win11
      resourceName: Win11 # Need to use resourceName
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:   
            steps:
            - powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal; isOutput=true]0703test"
              name: MyOutputVar

- stage: B
  jobs:
  - deployment: VMDeployWin10pro
    displayName: Deploy to Win10pro
    environment: 
      name: env-Win10pro
      resourceName: Win10pro-TFS202
      resourceType: virtualMachine

variables:
       myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.A.VMDeployWin11.outputs['Deploy_Win11.MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
    strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:   
            steps:
            - powershell: Write-Host "$(myStageAVar)"
              displayName: Pass variable from deployment job to deployment job 

Syntax
$[stageDependencies. <stage-name>. <deployment-job-name>.outputs['Deploy_<resource-name>.<step-name>. <variable-name>']]


Glad to know it's resolved and thanks for the sharing! Yes, if you need runOnce strategy plus a resourceType, you need to use '<job-name>_<resource-name>.<step-name>.<variable-name>'] in output section. You can check the doc  i mentioned below.
